# Vulkan create instance VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, vulkan

I'm trying to create a VkInstance to get started with Vulkan and I've already run into an undocumented error. This is all the code that I have so far:

```
VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo = {};
applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
applicationInfo.pNext = NULL;
applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "<game>";
applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
applicationInfo.pEngineName = "<engine>";
applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

// setup the instance info
VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = {};
instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
instanceInfo.pNext = NULL;
instanceInfo.flags = 0;
instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
instanceInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = NULL;
instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
instanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;

// create the vk instance which is used to do stuff in vulkan
VkInstance instance;
VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, NULL, &instance);
```

the result after this is VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY. All the documentation says about this is that vkCreateInstance might return this. Super helpful -_-. What am I missing here?

Comment: "*All the documentation says about this is that vkCreateInstance might return this.*" If the documentation talks about it... how is it "undocumented"?

Comment: The behavior is undocumented. Every job I've ever worked has required enumeration of the output, as well as the inputs and states that would result in those outputs. Without documenting that behavior, they may as well be returning NULL for all outputs.

Comment: "*`VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY` A host memory allocation has failed.*" That's from the documentation. That's all it says, and that's all it *needs* to say. And quite frankly, that's all it *can* say. Because there's no way to know exactly *why* the host could not allocate memory. Maybe it's something in your system, but with so many systems around, there's no way to be able to enumerate all of the possible causes of it. When dealing in cross-platform low-level programming, there are going to be cases where an error is just unrecoverable.

Comment: That being said, it's far more likely that Vulkan is not properly installed in your system in some fashion.

Comment: This means system memory? As in a request to allocate memory in windows has failed? I have a slightly old video card, (radeon HD 6970), but I was fairly sure the driver supported it, but this is not the error I would be expecting. I've reinstalled vulkan twice already with no success.

Comment: is it required that I specify a platform specific extension? I've tried setting the enabled extension count and ppEnabledExtensionNames like from [this](https://harrylovescode.gitbooks.io/vulkan-api/content/chap02/chap02.html) tutorial, but I get the same error.

Comment: @FatalCatharsis I am not sure how HD 6970 would be supported. It is not yet GCN. AMD offers only "legacy" drivers, which predate Vulkan. ;; No, extensions are not required to create an instance. And yes, HOST means system memory (the one from `malloc`). ;; It is possibly a bug and `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER` should be returned. Try also running `vulkaninfo` to eliminate error on your part.

Comment: Afaik there is no Vulkan support for the HD6790 (at least not a single report for it in my database at http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/) and as @krOoze hinted the ```VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY```result value is a bug and is misleading. Are you using the latest Vulkan SDKs and runtime? If not, try updating and see if you get the correct return value.

Comment: @SaschaWillems Sorry for it taking so long to get back to this, I haven't had a lot of free time lately. I've just uninstalled and reinstalled from scratch, version 1.0.33, and I still receive the exact same error. It's weird, it feels like my vid card isn't that old, but looking back, it's already been like 6 years. Anyway, do you think I should open up a bug ticket for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the Vulkan SDK, which was reproduced and patched in issue #629 https://vulkan.lunarg.com/issue/view/584553649ab0fa4b673614cb.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your installation is correct. For development you should have a graphics driver supporting Vulkan and the Vulkan SDK from LunarG.

Start by verifying your installation and run demo programs: `vulkaninfo` and `cube`. If either doesn't work, chances are your card/driver isn't capable of using Vulkan.

Finally, your app should be linked against vulkan-1 library. `vkCreateInstance` is serviced by the loader from the SDK (Vulkan runtime), so normally there should be no reason for it to fail, other than no compatible drivers available.