# vkAllocateDescriptorSets returns VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

Tags: vulkan

I wrote vulkan code on my laptop that worked, and then I got a new laptop and now running it, the program aborts because vkAllocateDescriptorSets() returns VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY.

I doubt that it is actually out of memory, and I know it can allocate some memory because VkCreateInstance() doesn't fail like in this stack overflow post: [Vulkan create instance VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856564/vulkan-create-instance-vk-out-of-host-memory).

EDIT: Also, I forgot to mention, vkAllocateDescriptorSets() only returns VK_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY the second time I run it.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

`vkAllocateDescriptorSets` allocates descriptors from a pool. So while such allocation could fail due to a lack of host/device memory, there are two other things that could cause failure. There may simply not be enough memory in the pool to allocate the number of descriptors/sets you asked for. Or there could be enough memory, but repeated allocations/deallocations have fragmented the pool such that the allocations cannot be made.

The case of allocating more descriptors/sets than are available should *never happen*. After all, you *know* how many descriptors&sets you put into that pool, so you should know exactly when you'll run out. This is an error state that a working application can guarantee it will never encounter. Though the VK_KHR_maintenance1 extension did add support for this circumstance: `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_POOL_MEMORY_KHR`.

However, if you've screwed up your pool creation in some way, you will get this possibility. Of course, since there's no error code for it (outside of the extension), the implementation will have to provide a different error code: either host or device memory exhaustion.

But again, this is a *programming error* on your part, not something you should ever expect to see with working code. In particular, even if you request that extension, do not keep allocating from a pool until it stops giving you memory. That's just bad coding.

For the fragmentation case, they do have an error code: `VK_ERROR_FRAGMENTED_POOL`. However, the Khronos Group screwed up. See, the first few releases of Vulkan didn't include this error code; it was added later. Which means that implementations from before the adding of this error code (and likely afterwards) had to pick an inappropriate error code to return. Again, either host or device memory.

So you basically have to treat any failure of this function as either fragmentation, programming error (ie: you asked for more stuff than you put into the pool), or something else. In all cases, it's not something you can recover from at runtime.

Since it appeared to work once, odds are good that you probably just allocated more stuff than the pool contains. So you should make sure that you add enough stuff to the pool before allocating from it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not allocated enough memory in the pool.  I solved it by creating multiple pools.  One for each descriptor set.